# Connecting to hosts postgresql from django app running in a docker container

Tags: docker, postgresql, django

I am trying to connect to my hosts postgresql server (version 14) from my django app running in a docker container.

here are my settings

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services: 
   web:
     build: .
       container_name: dm-api
     volumes: 
       - .:/code
       - static:/code/dojo_manager/static
       - media:/code/dojo_manager/media
     expose: 
       - 8080
     extra_hosts:
       - "database:172.17.0.1"
     command: bash -c "systemctl restart cron && python manage.py collectstatic --no input && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn --workers=3 dojo_manager.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8080"
   nginx:
     restart: always
     build: ./nginx/
     volumes: 
        - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - ./logs/:/code/logs
        - static:/code/static
        - media:/code/media
     ports: 
        - "1221:80"
     links:
        - web  
 volumes: 
   media:
   static:
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/16           md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
```

ifconfig:

```
 docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    inet6 fe80::42:41ff:fe7c:b9e9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:41:7c:b9:e9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 40651  bytes 6850716 (6.8 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 51087  bytes 570351402 (570.3 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

however when I start the container I get the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "database" (172.17.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.19.0.2", user "dtuser", database "dtdb", SSL encryption
connection to server at "database" (172.17.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.19.0.2", user "dtuser", database "dtdb", no encryption
```

I have tried all sorts of online resources and documentations. However, I cant seem to get the connection running.

Any tips/help is much appreciated.
Best
Benedict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite litereally in that error message.
There is no hba entry for the host 172.19.0.2. You only allow connections from 172.16.0.0/16. What you Probably want is 172.16.0.0/12

Comment: thanks i just added ```host    all             all             172.19.0.0/16           md5``` and it worked . no idea how i missed this.. been working on it for hours